When I try to type something, I get a prohibited icon
When I try to type something, I get a weird prohibited icon pop-up. I am currently using Indian (rupees) keyboard, and there is no hardware issue with my PC.


On Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS I get the "block" icon if press the "Play/Pause" media key on a UK keyboard. Do you get the "block" item for any key you press, and is it stopping normal keyboard operation?
